# from unix ffmpeg bash pipe to windows ''universe"

Tags: windows, powershell, ffmpeg, pipe, stdout

I am trying to "translate" some script from bash to windows powershell

I tried to pass the simplest

```
 ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vn -sn -map 0:a:0 -f flac - | ffmpeg -i - -c:a aac oiji.m4a
```

the result is a failure

using `-f wav -` another failure

there is a way to make it work?

thank you

Comment: Seems like an odd choice to pipe from ffmpeg to ffmpeg, using an input that is probably already AAC and encoding that to AAC.

Comment: I know, but it is the simplest piping, if i cannot figure out how use it, I cant use a ffmpeg > sox > ffmpeg or ffmpeg (with hardware decoding) > x264  (my personal build, an old build but customized and tailored for my needs)